# HTTP requests stops working after some time

Tags: http, mono, webclient

I have strange problem with my Game written in Unity (Mono). I have login functionality and then, after successfull login i'm sending some kind of keep-alive requests to ensure token is updated (I'm sending it every 30s).

The problem is, that after some time (sometimes it's 1 hour, sometimes 2.5 hours) all my requests have timeout status.

To be sure about my connection status I made some checks in code: I'm making simple GET to http://google.com and to main website of my API (not an API call. Just website GET). When I got timeout on API next time i figured out that:

- After 1 timeout I have it always. Restarting application helps
- I'm getting timeouts on API call and on GET request for base API website
- Google is still responding with status 200 (no timeouts here)

Implementation:
On beginning i've been using `RestSharp` to handle requests, but the problem occured and there was a decision to throw `RestSharp` away and now we're using classic `WebClient`

```
class BetterWebClient : WebClient
{
    private WebRequest _Request = null;
    public TimeSpan? Timeout { get; set; }
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        this._Request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if ( Timeout.HasValue )
        {
            _Request.Timeout = (int)Timeout.Value.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
        else
        {
            _Request.Timeout = 10*1000; //10s
        }
        if (this._Request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            ((HttpWebRequest)this._Request).AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        }

        return this._Request;
    }
}
```

My HandleRequest function (which also calls Google and API website) looks like this:

```
public static void HandleRequest<TR>(string url, RestResponse<TR> executeGetRequest) where TR : new()
{
    using (BetterWebClient w = new BetterWebClient() {Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)})
    {
        try
        {
            string downloadString = w.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
            Debug.Log("Google request: OK");
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            Debug.LogError("Google request failed");
        }

        try
        {
            string downloadString = w.DownloadString("myAPIwebsite");
            Debug.Log("WorldOfRescue.com request: OK");
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            Debug.LogError("WorldOfRescue.com request failed");
        }
    }
    var client = new BetterWebClient() {Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)};
    client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    try
    {
        string downloadString = client.DownloadString(url);

        Debug.Log("Request for "+url+ " completed. Response: " + downloadString);
    }
    catch ( WebException e )
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Status);

        throw;
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why it happens? It looks like something is blocking me to send request to specific website, but in same time other website is working fine.